# storing time and day of week

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

**Challenge :**
I have a requirement in which I have to implement recurring events. I am storing day of the week , time and the date range for which the event will reoccur.

**Possible solution:**
Storing time and day of week as string and enumeration.
Storing current and setting the time and day for that day ?

**Question** :
What is the best practice on storing time and day of week ?

EDT: I am using SQL Server Database

Comment: I generally prefer to use unix timestamps. They are very simple to manipulate and most database systems have built-in support for translating them to strings.

Comment: @Hunter What do you get from Unix timestamps? They're not human readable (well, for most humans anyway), you have to convert them before performing any type of date/time operations, and there are no built-in functions to do so in SQL Server - you have to perform the DATEADD yourself every time.

Comment: @AaronBertrand The database is just a storage unit, there is no need for a human to read it. Your queries can transform them into a readable format. It is just a preference for me I suppose.

Comment: @Hunter in SQL Server a datetime is not stored as a human readable value anyway (it's stored as two ints). But it's quite convenient that client tools such as Management Studio and many providers and languages understand that it is a datetime and not some big random number. You've kind of explained why you don't think datetime has any advantage, but you still haven't explained what makes a Unix timestamp "preferable."

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is to have computed columns representing the parts that you're after.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.foo
(
  bar DATETIME,
  bar_day_of_week AS DATEPART(WEEKDAY, bar),
  bar_time AS CONVERT(TIME, bar)
);

INSERT dbo.foo(bar) SELECT GETDATE();

SELECT bar, bar_day_of_week, bar_time FROM dbo.foo;
```

Answer (score 2):

This best approach might dependson the database you are using.  But, there are two general approaches, both quite reasonable.

The first is to store dates and times in the native format for the database.  Most databases have functions to extract day of the week and time from a date time type.  You would write your queries using these functions.  Typically, you would store these as one field, but sometimes you might want to separate the date and time portions.

The second is to have a calendar table.  A calendar table would have a date or dateid as a key, and then contain columns for what you want to know about it.  Day of the week would be an obvious column.

A calendar table is the preferred solution in some situations.  For instance, if you are going to internationalize your application, then being able to get day of the week from a table makes it easier to get the string English, Greek, Chinese, Russian, Swahili, or whatever your favorite language is.  Or, if you want to keep track of specific holidays, then a calendar table can store this information as well.  Or, if you have a business running on a strange financial calendar (such as 5-4-4), then a calendar table is a good choice.

In either case, you do not need to store redundant date information in the table.  You should derive it, either from a built-in function or by looking up what you want in a reference table.